# I am unable to refer to things inside my activity, like buttons, and radiogroups

Tags: java, android

so I am trying to create an activity, and then add onclick listeners to it, but it wont let me refer. So the moment I open this activity in my app, my app crashes, saying 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference'

I have no idea why this is happening. I have correctly names them in accordance with the xml file as well.

Please help.

```
public class SubtaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etSubtaskName;
    Button btnDone;
    RadioGroup radgrpPri, radgrpTime;
    RadioButton radbtnPriHigh, radbtnPriMed, radbtnPriLow, radbtnTimeMore, radbtnTimeMed, radbtnTimeLess;
    boolean priHigh, priMed, priLow, timeMore, timeMed, timeLess;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        btnDone = findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
        radgrpPri = findViewById(R.id.radgrpPri);
        radgrpTime = findViewById(R.id.radgrpTime);
        radbtnPriHigh = findViewById(R.id.radbtnPriHigh);
        radbtnPriMed = findViewById(R.id.radbtnPriMed);
        radbtnPriLow = findViewById(R.id.radbtnPriLow);
        radbtnTimeMore = findViewById(R.id.radbtnTimeMore);
        radbtnTimeMed = findViewById(R.id.radbtnTimeMed);
        radbtnTimeLess = findViewById(R.id.radbtnTimeLess);
        etSubtaskName = findViewById(R.id.etSubtaskName);


        radgrpPri.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                if (radbtnPriHigh.isChecked())
                {
                    priHigh = true;
                    priLow = false;
                    priMed = false;
                }
                else if (radbtnPriMed.isChecked())
                {
                    priHigh = false;
                    priLow = false;
                    priMed = true;
                }
                else if (radbtnPriLow.isChecked())
                {
                    priHigh = false;
                    priLow = true;
                    priMed = false;
                }

            }
        });

        radgrpTime.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                if (radbtnTimeMore.isChecked())
                {
                    timeMore = true;
                    timeMed = false;
                    timeLess = false;
                }
               else if (radbtnTimeMed.isChecked())
                {
                    timeMore = false;
                    timeMed = true;
                    timeLess = false;
                }
               else if (radbtnTimeLess.isChecked())
                {
                    timeMore = false;
                    timeMed = false;
                    timeLess = true;
                }
            }
        });




        btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               String name = etSubtaskName.getText().toString().trim();

               Intent intent = new Intent(SubtaskActivity.this, TaskInfo.class);
               intent.putExtra("subtaskName", name);
               intent.putExtra("priHigh", priHigh);
               intent.putExtra("priMed", priMed);
               intent.putExtra("priLow", priLow);
               intent.putExtra("timeMore", timeMore);
               intent.putExtra("timeMed", timeMed);
               intent.putExtra("timeLess", timeLess);
               startActivity(intent);




            }
        });





    }

}
```

XML File :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/it"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSubtaskPriorityHeading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="@string/priority_of_subtask"
            android:textColor="#B8AEAE"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgrpPri"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radbtnPriHigh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/red"
                android:text="@string/high"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radbtnPriMed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/yellow"
                android:text="@string/medium"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radbtnPriLow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/green"
                android:text="@string/low"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTimeWeightHeading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="@string/time_this_subtask_may_consume"
            android:textColor="#B8AEAE"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/floating_hint_time_minutes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FlotatingHintStyle">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etSubtaskName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:hint="@string/name_your_subtask"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="#B8AEAE"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgrpTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radbtnTimeMore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/red"
                android:text="@string/more"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radbtnTimeMed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/yellow"
                android:text="@string/medium"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radbtnTimeLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/green"
                android:text="@string/less"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/done"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/orange_accent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Added the xml file.

Comment: u forget `setContentView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call in `onCreate` method `setContentView(R.layout.youractivity)`. If you didn't, Android doesn't know what to render, so there are no views for you to provide.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.youractivity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set your (xml)layout file to `setContentView` in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

}
```